# Tamanho de imagem ideal

Tags: android, material-design

Alguém saberia me informar qual o tamanho ideal para esse tipo de imagem, onde faço a configuração para deixa nesse mesmo formato da imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tudo que você precisa saber está nesse link, é a guideline do Google para lista, espaçamentos, tamanhos e etc. segue o link. https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-specs

Comment: Então, essa é minha dúvida. Lá tem todas as dimensões, menos o tamanho da imagem em sí.

Comment: a sim, desculpe. são 40dp. caso queira visitar ta nesse link escrito. http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size

Comment: É isso ai cara, obrigado.

Comment: vou adicionar como resposta da pergunta e você marca como respondida.

Comment: Tudo bem marco sim.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a guideline do Material Design, é **40dp** o tamanho do **ImageView**.
fonte: http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size